# Autocomplete not working on our web application login form

Tags: autocomplete

We have in our company a web application which we designed.

the person who design the UI is no longer available to us and I'm trying to figure out something in his code.

for some reason, on the login window, the browser won't suggest to save the user name and password.

it's not working on chrome and explorer, but it does works on ForeFox.

this is the link to the login window: https://console.edge-bi.com/v29/login.html

i already checked the browsers settings for autocomplte and it does work for any other websites.

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For me it works with Chrome Browser, Ubuntu

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430129/how-to-make-chrome-remember-password-for-an-ajax-form