# Chrome, Safari and Opera do not remember password on simple form

Tags: forms, google-chrome, authentication, safari, opera

I first had the problem with an AJAX login, and after looking for a solution for hours I thought I would try something as simple as this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="login_form" action="login.html" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="login_username" value="" />
            <input type="password" id="login_password" value="" />
            <input type="submit" id="login_submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It goes to login.html but does not offer to save the password! I thought it might be a localhost issue so i deployed on the server and still, Chrome does not offer to store the password. FF and IE work as expected but Chrome, Safari and Opera do not.

"*Offer to save passwords I enter on the web*" is checked.

"*Never saved*" is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow. This **should** be noted somewhere. *I suspect it probably is but I just could not find it...*

The solution is the name tag in both username and password fields. If these are missing then Chrome will not offer to save the password. Once I added the name tags Chrome and Opera started to offer to save the password.

Safari is still not doing it.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form id="login_form" action="login.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="login_username" name="login_username" value="" />
      <input type="password" id="login_password" name="password_username" value="" />
      <input type="submit" id="login_submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```